# Spring Boot getting invalid property value with @Value for userName

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Why Spring Boot giving me wrong property value when i use this code

```
@Component
public class MyComponent implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Value("${userName}")
    private String user;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("===================: "+user);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
userName=admin
```

It is not printing 'admin', it is printing my windows user name.

Comment: variables in `application.properties` are overidden by env variables. You may chose another name for your variable.

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707675/7820277

Answer (score 2):

From [Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) :

Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are considered in the following order:

1- Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).

[...]

10- **OS environment variables**.

[...]

14- Application properties outside of your packaged jar (**application.properties** and YAML variants).

As you can see, your OS env variable take precedence over variables defined in `application.properties` which is very useful when you want to override them.

You should consider renaming your variable so that it does not conflicts with windows' environment variable names.